# How to turn direction of model in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Parted screengrab:

[image]

Clicking on the line-art map, I see the model turns in complex ways. How can I control the direction?

Comment: You swipe on the street view to change your facing. Are you asking something else?

Comment: @ale, Nice, didn't know I could drag the top pane. how'd you get that?

Comment: Using Street View on the web.

Comment: @ale, (btw you can just post first it as answer) You referring to https://www.instantstreetview.com or Google's one?

Comment: Google Street View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pegman (that's his name) is indicating the direction of the Street View. Simply drag the Street View image to change your facing.